# Using loops and if statements with the Scanner class

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program that scans through a text file line by line and adds certain integers together on each line. The text file in question has the following format:

```
01-Jan-2012     ED521D  4       100     30      1499       M    N Brewer
02-Jan-2012     ED925H  5       488     30      1499       A    B Saini
02-Jan-2012     JF560D  3       275     40      949        M    S Cooper
02-Jan-2012     ZK201U  1       359     40      474        R    S Chadwick
```

My aim is to add up the numbers in the third column (4,5,3) if the character in the penultimate column is either an "M" or "A". So the program should output 12 using the text file above.   Here's what i've got so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String filename = "policy.txt";
Scanner input = null;
double itemAmount = 0; 
String text = "";
int policyCount = 0;

input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
while (input.hasNext()) { 

     String read = input.nextLine(); 
     String clean = read.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""); 

     char policyType = clean.charAt(59); 
    if (input.hasNextInt()) {

         itemAmount = itemAmount + input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
     if (policyType == 'A' || policyType == 'M' ){
        policyCount++;
      }     
     } 
   else if(input.hasNext()){
        text = input.next(); 
   }
  }
    System.out.println(policyCount);
System.out.println(itemAmount);
}
```

Comment: So what's not working as expected?

Comment: The approach seems more complicated that it needs to be, I would utilize the split and equals methods of the String class in a loop for each line in the file.

Comment: The values I receive when I print "policyCount" and "itemAmount" are 0, which is wrong. Sorry, I should've clarified that in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String filename = "policy.txt";
        Scanner input = null;
        double itemAmount = 0;
        int policyCount = 0;

        input = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            String read = input.nextLine();
            String clean = read.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");

            char policyType = clean.charAt(59);

            if (policyType == 'A' || policyType == 'M')
            {
                policyCount++;
                itemAmount += Character.getNumericValue((clean.charAt(24)));
            }
        }
        input.close();
        System.out.println(policyCount);
        System.out.println(itemAmount);            
    }
}
```

Note that this will only work for single digit numbers in the 24th column. If it might contain more digits you'll have to do a substring on clean and then use Double.valueOf().

Answer (score 0):

I guess would want to put

```
itemAmount = itemAmount + input.nextInt();
```

Inside

```
if (policyType == 'A' || policyType == 'M' ){

}
```

Hope this helps.

Also, you have not used 'read' String. You are seemingly skipping lines.
Use read.split(" ") to get array of tokens.
Then use 3rd token to parse as Integer.
Add it if the condition is true.